# Troubleshooting java native memory leak

Tags: linux, java

I've noticed that java app I run leaks memory (not capped and quite fast, can take all the memory in under 10 mins and force swap to activate which impacts performance). I know that such issue does not affect other users (including at least one linux user), so most likely problem is not in app and rather in software (jvm and libs, drivers). App requires java 8, issue persists on both openjdk and oracle java. I can't modify app and it seems I can't influence the way app is launched (it is updated and launched by another java app, and grabbing cmdline from `ps` and manually launching it with it doesn't work (it crashes)), so I can't attach java agents (certain profilers require it, not sure if profiler is needed), but I can attach to process using ltrace and similar utilities. I've examined process memory maps and found that leak consists of 1mb regions mapped to `/dev/dri/renderD128` (new ones appear, old ones persist), so issue is likely related to graphic drivers (but I've updated my drivers to actual version (padoka ppa for ubuntu) and issue persists). I've found several bugreports about openjfx leaking memory (javafx is used in this app), but proposed workarounds didn't work. Not sure if it's useful, but I also noticed segfault signals when using `ltrace`, these don't crash app and it seems their appearance is tied to appearance of mentioned `/dev/dri/renderD128` regions.

---

1. How can I narrow down the issue (so I know what exactly is causing it, so I can fix it or submit bugreport or something)?
2. Is it possible to externally force process to free certain regions of memory, and if so, how is it done? (I guess ugly workaround would be monitoring appearance of these regions and removing them once in a while)

---

I can provide more details on hardware and software I use if needed

Comment: You might experiment with command-line options to control garbage collection (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/commands_gc.html) and memory allocations (see https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control). Java applications I use require memory management, e.g., *-Xmx1G* .

Comment: It's native memory leak (not in jvm heap) so tweaking garbage collection won't help, and mentioned options are present in cmdline that launches app.

Comment: Have you tried changing them?

Comment: No, but again, it is **not** an in-heap leak.

Comment: If the problem is increase of `/dev/dri/render*` mappings, then this hints that graphics resources are not properly released, so I wouldn't call it "memory leak". If you have sources and are somewhat familiar with them, try removing stuff until the problem goes away, so you can narrow down to what particular resources are not properly released. A minimal example with this behaviour really really helps if the problem is in some library/driver, and you need to make a bugreport.